# Serve cephFS files over HTTP (or S3?)

Tags: amazon-s3, containers, ceph, lxd

I have a CEPH+LXD cluster configuration.
And I would like to *serve* the files in the container over HTTP (S3,whatever doesn't matter).

Is there a way to do this using the `rgw` service?

Like can I point it to serve the cephFS directories and stuff?

In my head it works something like this

`S3 client -> Same RADOS object <- cephFS client`

is this even possible?
and if so can we extend even further with ext4 cephRBD volumes?

Comment: That's not how it works, those are different protocols so the objects within ceph are stored and organized differently (and in different pools).

Comment: thanks for confirming my suspicions @eblock